# Are questions related to Hadoop welcome on scicomp?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've been using Hadoop for some time now, and after carefully looking it seems that the only place to ask questions about implementation details is still the official Hadoop mailing lists.

I'm talking about many different parts of Hadoop, like Map/Reduce, Pig, Hive, ...

There are a few questions on StackOverflow, but except from a few users, I find these questions with very low view counts there, and very low answer rate as well.

When I type "Hadoop" on area51, the first site returned is this one though... There is indeed a proposal for "distributed systems" there, but it's been in the definition phase for a year and I have doubts it will ever see the light of day.

I wanted to consider asking questions about Hadoop here, but after doing a quick search it seems there are no questions on that topic.

So I was wondering if here would be a good place to ask questions specifically related to Hadoop, since it also deals with big computations? Or should I consider creating a separate proposal on Area51?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hadoop and the design/analysis of Map-Reduce algorithms are on-topic, particularly for research-focused questions.  Whether we have the experts to answer the questions is another can of beans.  Give it a try and we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I meant not only algorithms-centered question, but also questions about scalability, like how to design my table in Hive, how to configure Hive to use a MySQL driver for metastore, how to create this UDF in Pig, ... Do you think it's still on topic, or questions should really revolve around the algorithms themselves?

Comment: I think that if you're willing to try and answer questions that you ask, or put effort into making the question not easy to answer on Google, the worst thing that happens is nobody answers it and we try it out on SO or another one of the sites on the network.  I'm afraid we don't have enough domain knowledge to answer these questions, but I would like us to :)

Comment: I understand thanks :) I definitely have a few questions in mind about distributed algorithms who will be a good fit here then, but i think for Hadoop-specifics as per your advice i'll just try on SO, or maybe create a proposal on area51 too since this would be a nice complement to scicomp.